# Where was the concept of Yugas discussed first?

Tags: vedas, puranas, manu-smriti, yuga

The concept of *chaturyuga*, where does it trace its origin from. In which of the text(s) the concept is mentioned as it is known to us today.

Comment: The yugas were first discussed in Puranas